# Flutter iOS memory leak when loading image from network/file system

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, memory

In my app i am using image picker to select an image from the file system, uploading it to firebase storage and either showing it via `ExtendedImage.memory` or `ExtendedImage.network`. After doing the process once or twice and then going around the app, the app on ios just randomly crashes. This error is not reproducible in dev mode, only when the app is installed via firebases app distribution or via app store/testflight. Furthemore, the issues is not reproducible on most ios deviced but only a selected few, primarily iPhone 14 with ios version 16.6.1. The error i'm getting in crashlytics is as follows:

`Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000fa62162d0`

followed by:

`<compiler-generated> - Line 4338043708 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable (@in_guaranteed Notification) -> () + 4338043708`

I've been playing around with the properties of `ExtendedImage`, either clearing cache upon disposing or not caching at all but nothing helped. I assume the issue is related to the image being uploaded/showed because it only happens when the user changes image on a certain page. If user fills out the page without uploading image app does not crash.

Any ideas/suggestions what the above means, i've been browsing through multiple questions and trying the solutions but without too much luck. Flutter version in question is 3.13.7, firebase and image picker dependencies are updated to latest versions.

Comment: Looking at `(@in_guaranteed Notification) -> ()`  - Are you registering some notification handlers perhaps that cause problems?

Comment: no, the app doesn't support notifications. however i had the push notifications capability enabled for some time because i was recieving an email from apple that the app is missing push notifications entitlement, but i removed it recently

Comment: upon further investigation, i realised that i was using NotificationCenter to catch and override volume up/volume down button clicks and releases to implement some custom behaviour, and in the implementation was the issue. Even when the volume buttons were not used, the NotificationCenter caused the above issue. Thank you for the great hint @jraufeisen